# Seaborn scatterplot matrix - adding extra points with custom styles

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm doing a k-means clustering of activities on some open source projects on GitHub and am trying to plot the results together with the cluster centroids using [Seaborn Scatterplot Matrix](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html).

I can successfully plot the results of the clustering analysis (example tsv output below)

```text
user_id issue_comments  issues_created  pull_request_review_comments    pull_requests   category
1   0.14936519790888722 2.0100502512562812  0.0 0.60790273556231    Group 0
1882    0.11202389843166542 0.5025125628140703  0.0 0.0 Group 1
2   2.315160567587752   20.603015075376884  0.13297872340425532 1.21580547112462    Group 2
1789    36.8185212845407    82.91457286432161   75.66489361702128   74.46808510638297   Group 3
```

The problem I'm having is that I'd like to be able to also plot the centroids of the clusters on the matrix plot too. Currently I'm my plotting script looks like this:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from pylab import savefig
sns.set()

# By default, Pandas assumes the first column is an index
# so it will be skipped. In our case it's the user_id
data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('summary_clusters.tsv', sep='\t')

grid = sns.pairplot(data, hue="category", diag_kind="kde")
savefig('normalised_clusters.png', dpi = 150)
```

This produces the expected output: [image: matrix plot]

I'd like to be able to mark on each of these plots the *centroids* of the clusters. I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Create a new 'CENTROID' category and just plot this together with the other points.
2. Manually add extra points to the plots after calling `sns.pairplot(data, hue="category", diag_kind="kde")`.

If (1) is the solution then I'd like to be able to customise the marker (perhaps a star?) to make it more prominent.

If (2) I'm all ears. I'm pretty new to Seaborn and Matplotlib so any assistance would be very welcome :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pairplot` isn't going to be all that well suited to this sort of thing, but it's possible to make it work with a few tricks. Here's what I would do.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
sns.set_color_codes()

# Make some random iid data
cov = np.eye(3)
ds = np.vstack([np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0, 0], cov, 50),
                np.random.multivariate_normal([1, 1, 1], cov, 50)])
ds = pd.DataFrame(ds, columns=["x", "y", "z"])

# Fit the k means model and label the observations
km = KMeans(2).fit(ds)
ds["label"] = km.labels_.astype(str)
```

Now comes the non-obvious part: you need to create a dataframe with the centroid locations and then combine it with the dataframe of observations while identifying the centroids as appropriate using the `label` column:

```
centroids = pd.DataFrame(km.cluster_centers_, columns=["x", "y", "z"])
centroids["label"] = ["0 centroid", "1 centroid"]
full_ds = pd.concat([ds, centroids], ignore_index=True)
```

Then you just need to use `PairGrid`, which is a bit more flexible than `pairplot` and will allow you to map other plot attributes by the hue variable along with the color (at the expense of not being able to draw histograms on the diagonals):

```
g = sns.PairGrid(full_ds, hue="label",
                 hue_order=["0", "1", "0 centroid", "1 centroid"],
                 palette=["b", "r", "b", "r"],
                 hue_kws={"s": [20, 20, 500, 500],
                          "marker": ["o", "o", "*", "*"]})
g.map(plt.scatter, linewidth=1, edgecolor="w")
g.add_legend()
```

[image]

An alternate solution would be to plot the observations as normal then change the data attributes on the `PairGrid` object and add a new layer. I'd call this a hack, but in some ways it's more straightforward.

```
# Plot the data
g = sns.pairplot(ds, hue="label", vars=["x", "y", "z"], palette=["b", "r"])

# Change the PairGrid dataset and add a new layer
centroids = pd.DataFrame(km.cluster_centers_, columns=["x", "y", "z"])
g.data = centroids
g.hue_vals = [0, 1]
g.map_offdiag(plt.scatter, s=500, marker="*")
```

Comment: the alternative solution (updating data, then calling `g.map_offdiag` appears to be broken as of seaborn 0.11.0. I made an issue here: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2349

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but here is a generalized version of mwaskom's code to work with n clusters. Might save someone a few minutes

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
def cluster_scatter_matrix(data_norm, cluster_number):

     sns.set_color_codes()
     km = KMeans(cluster_number).fit(data_norm)
     data_norm["label"] = km.labels_.astype(str)
     centroids = pd.DataFrame(km.cluster_centers_, columns=data_norm.columns)
     centroids["label"] = [str(n)+" centroid" for n in range(cluster_number)]
     full_ds = pd.concat([data_norm, centroids], ignore_index=True)
     g = sns.PairGrid(full_ds, hue="label",
                 hue_order=[str(n) for n in range(cluster_number)]+[str(n)+" centroid" for n in range(cluster_number)],
                 #palette=["b", "r", "b", "r"],
                 hue_kws={"s": [ 20 for n in range(cluster_number)]+[500 for n in range(cluster_number)],
                          "marker": [ 'o' for n in range(cluster_number)]+['*' for n in range(cluster_number)]}
                )
     g.map(plt.scatter, linewidth=1, edgecolor="w")
     g.add_legend()
```